# Fetched data is returned in Proxy, not in "normal" Object

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

What I basically want is to save data fetched from api to variable.

```
export default defineComponent({
    name: "Neo",
    setup() {
        const loading = ref<boolean>(true);
        const route = useRoute();
        const data = ref();

        onMounted( async () => {
            await axios.get(`/neo/${route.params.id}`)
            .then( response => {
                data.value = response.data;
                console.log(data);
            })
        })
        

        return { loading, data }
    }
```

The problem is that fetched data is a Proxy object and I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like described in the [Vue3 documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref), you can get the value from a reactive variable (what you call proxy object) by using the `value` property, i. e. in your case using

```
console.log(data.value);
```

Comment: I get it now. Before, I tried to acces the data by value property wich in that case gave me a Proxy. I should just call "data" itself to get fetched data from api.