# Sending array of objects data from Vue.js to Laravel mailable

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, email

Hello i am doing and app where  i am using Vue 3 integrated with Laravel 9, and at some point, i have to send an email, with data from my front-end. And i am creating the email with the Mailable class of Laravel,  I am able to send an email with almost all the data i need.

My problem is that one of the data i want to send in the email, is inside an array of objects, that i want to use to populate a table inside my email, and it is not working.  Since the email is working and the only problem i have is with trying to display array values inside my emails,  i believe the problem is, or in my controller, or in my email blade, or in my vue component

Here are my files.

The function on my vue component that sends the email (i tried with Vue proxy directly, and then tried to convert it to array and none worked)

```
 sentMail(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var obj = this;
                 
             //    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.compras)))
                  console.log(this.soma)
                 alert("Concretizou a compra. Veja o seu email");
           
                 axios.post('mail-send', {  
                     nome: this.nome,  
                     email: this.email,
                     transportadora: this.transportadora,
                     compras: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.compras)),
                     soma: this.soma,
                     
                    
                 }).then(function (response) {  
                     obj.output = response.data;  
                 })  
                 .catch(function (error) {  
                     obj.output = error.response.data;  
                 });   
                 this.compras=[];
                
                },
```

The function on my controller that send the email

```
 public function mailSend(Request $request) {

        $email = $request->email;

        

        $data = [
            'nome' =>  $request->nome,
            'transportadora' => $request->transportadora, 
            'soma' => $request->soma,
            'compras'=>$request->compras
        ];

        Mail::to($email)->send(new ComprasMail($data));

   

       return response()->json([$request->all()]);  


    }
```

the part in my email blade template i am trying to call the elements of the array

```
@foreach($data['compras'] as $compra)
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">{{$compra.nome}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">{{$compra.qtd}}</td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">{{$compra.valor}}</td>


</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And here is how i create the array(that it converts to Proxy) so you can see the 3 components of my object

```
addTable(){
                 var single = this
 
                 axios.get('/get_produtos/'+ single.choosed)
                      .then((response)=>{
                        single.compras.push({nome:response.data.nome,qtd:single.novaCompra.qtd,valor:(+(single.novaCompra.qtd*response.data.preco).toFixed(2))});
                      single.novaCompra = {nome:"",qtd:"",valor:""};
                      
                     
                      })
```

Thank You in Advance

Edit: Noticed i had an '  in the wrong place, when is calling one of the components of the array, but even after i removed it, it sill don't work

Comment: What you try to do using both JSON.parse and JSON.stringify? You can pass `compras` value as stringified json and then parse at PHP using json_decode

Comment: My objective, was since Vue.js turns my array into a Proxy, and when i sent it directly to my Laravel Controller, i am not able to access his data in my email template, so i was trying to change it to an normal array.  However i tried your suggestion and it is still not working

Comment: @ArthurShlain  it worked now.   Noticed that during my twerking, for some reason i  changed in for each $data['compras]?  to $compras and that is the reason why was not working .   Thank you for the help

Comment: See also this interesting thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903532/2453148

Comment: thank you!  finally was able to solve my problem